# Pause loop for a second after every five iterations

Tags: javascript, loops, timeout, sleep, wait

For my program I have to make a 100 JSON requests. Unfortunately only 5 calls per second are allowed. Since I am making all the JSON request with a for loop (is the best way), I have to pause the loop after every 5 calls for 1 second.

```
function Hello() {
   $("#randomdiv").show();
   for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
       if (i%5 == 0 && i>0) {
         sleep(1000);
       }   
       $.getJSON(JSONreq, function(data) {Just a JSON request, nothing special}) 
    };  
};
```

The `sleep(1000)` causes the whole page to freeze for a about 20 seconds and prevents the `#randomdiv` from appearing before the JSON requests are made.

What can I do to solve this problem? 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Use a timer: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: @Alfie I cannot figure out how to use the timer only every fifth iteration. Which of those two timers is better for me?

Comment: You probably would want `setInterval()` because that continues to loop until you stop it. If you want to execute code every 5th time, you could use a global variable integer that you increment by 1 each loop, and then check if it == 4, if it does - execute your code and reset the number to 0, otherwise, just add 1 to the number and exit the function

Comment: An alternative implementation: If you'd have phrased the question as I need to pause loop for 0.2 seconds per iteration you might have found this an easier problem to solve.

Comment: @user814064 Oh man, I cannot believe I haven't thought of that. That's a lot easier! Thanks

Comment: So the rule is 5 requests per second. Don't you think that sending exactly 5 requests every second is cutting it a little close? Fluctuations in network traffic or whatever will mean that the server sometimes receives more than 5 requests in a 5-second interval. What happens then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timeout with a closure:

```
function Hello() {
   $("#randomdiv").show();
   var loop = getLoop();
   loop();
};

function getLoop() {
    var count = 0;
    var func = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            $.getJSON(JSONreq, function(data) {Just a JSON request, nothing special}) 
        }
        if (++count < 20) {
            setTimeout(func, 1000);
        }
    }
    return func;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
function Hello() {
    $("#randomdiv").show();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var interval = 0;
        if (i % 5 == 0 && i > 0) {
            interval = 1000;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            getJson()
        }, interval);
    };
}

function getJson() {
    $.getJSON(JSONreq, function (data) {
        Just a JSON request, nothing special
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `setTimeout` make the function run asynchronously? So if you run this, I think it will first go through the `for` loop 100 times very quickly and set the timeouts, and then one second later they will all run at the same time. That's assuming that running `setTimeout` with a delay of `0` doesn't do anything, which imo is probably not the case. You may find that it runs `getJson()` immediately 80 times, then 20 times one second later.